# Find processes reacting to a given keybinding

Tags: x11

Is there a way to know which processes are listening to a given key binding?

For example, suppose I want to know which programs will do something when I press Ctrl+g. I guess the X server manages this, but how can I view the listening events?

To be clear, I'm not asking for how to set key bindings on X, but for how to find all processes which will do something when some combination of key presses (or mouse events for that matter) is used, possibly using command line tools.

Comment: @don_crissti that's what I'm asking indeed. I didn't know the correct  terminology so I didn't see that post. Unfortunately It doesn't have a definitive answer though.

Answer (score -1):

It probably depends on the distribution but Preferences / (System Settings / ) Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts might point you in the right direction for desktop manager keybindings.

Most applications have their own specific keyboard shortcuts to access application functions.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking ( if I understood you). I edited the post to clarify the question

Comment: If I am understanding the question this is about programming right? In that case the question can better be asked at stackoverflow I presume.

Comment: Why do you say that? There is nothing about programming here, I just want to know the processes which are listening to a given keyboard/whatever event

Comment: The reason I said that was because of the 'old days' when I used to develop tools in visual studio, where I had almost the same question and looked for APIs to talk to. While reading your question where you state 'but how can I view the listening events' the events part brought me some old memories about 'hooking' into application events...